Issues with Creating a Conda Environment from environment.yml
I'm trying to create an environment from the environment.yml file I found here. I run the command:
conda env create -f environment.yml

While everything seems fine up to a certain point, it then terminates with errors. I have also tried creating the environment through Anaconda Navigator. I have uninstalled Anaconda, deleted temporary files and folders, and reinstalled Anaconda. I did everything from scratch again, and still, it has issues. Does anyone know what's going on?
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides requested wurlitzer 2.1.0**
  - nothing provides requested unixodbc 2.3.9**
  - nothing provides requested secretstorage 3.3.1**
  - nothing provides requested readline 8.1**
  - nothing provides requested patchelf 0.12**
  - nothing provides requested pango 1.45.3**
  - nothing provides requested ncurses 6.2**
  - nothing provides requested libxcb 1.14**
  - nothing provides requested libuuid 1.0.3**
  - nothing provides requested libtool 2.4.6**
  - nothing provides requested libstdcxx-ng 9.1.0**
  - nothing provides requested libgfortran-ng 7.3.0**
  - nothing provides requested libgcc-ng 9.1.0**
  - nothing provides requested libffi 3.3**
  - nothing provides requested libev 4.33**
  - nothing provides requested libedit 3.1.20210216**
  - nothing provides requested ld_impl_linux-64 2.33.1**
  - nothing provides requested jbig 2.1**
  - nothing provides requested harfbuzz 2.8.0**
  - nothing provides requested gstreamer 1.14.0**
  - nothing provides requested gst-plugins-base 1.14.0**
  - nothing provides requested gmp 6.2.1**
  - nothing provides requested glib 2.68.1**
  - nothing provides requested fontconfig 2.13.1**
  - nothing provides requested dbus 1.13.18**
  - package pyzmq-20.0.0-py36hd77b12b_1 requires zeromq >=4.3.3,<4.3.4.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package libglib-2.78.4-ha17d25a_0 requires zlib >=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ cairo 1.16.0**  is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ cairo 1.16.0 would require
│  │  └─ glib >=2.69.1,<3.0a0  with the potential options
│  │     ├─ glib 2.78.4 would require
│  │     │  └─ libglib 2.78.4 ha17d25a_0, which requires
│  │     │     └─ zlib >=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     └─ glib 2.69.1 would require
│  │        └─ pcre >=8.45,<9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  └─ cairo 1.16.0 would require
│     └─ fontconfig >=2.14.1,<3.0a0 , which requires
│        └─ expat >=2.4.9,<3.0a0 , which can be installed;
├─ dbus 1.13.18**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ expat 2.3.0**  is not installable because it conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
├─ fontconfig 2.13.1**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ glib 2.68.1**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ gmp 6.2.1**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ gst-plugins-base 1.14.0**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ gstreamer 1.14.0**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ harfbuzz 2.8.0**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ jbig 2.1**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ ld_impl_linux-64 2.33.1**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ libedit 3.1.20210216**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ libev 4.33**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ libffi 3.3**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ libgcc-ng 9.1.0**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ libgfortran-ng 7.3.0**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ libstdcxx-ng 9.1.0**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ libtool 2.4.6**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ libuuid 1.0.3**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ libxcb 1.14**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ ncurses 6.2**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ pango 1.45.3**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ patchelf 0.12**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ pcre 8.44**  is not installable because it conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
├─ pyzmq 20.0.0**  is installable and it requires
│  └─ zeromq >=4.3.3,<4.3.4.0a0 , which can be installed;
├─ readline 8.1**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ secretstorage 3.3.1**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ unixodbc 2.3.9**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ wurlitzer 2.1.0**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ zeromq 4.3.4**  is not installable because it conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
└─ zlib 1.2.11**  is not installable because it conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.


Did you ever find a solution to this? I am running into the same issue - probably a beginner's mistake on my side, though. Still, I do not quite yet get what I am doing wrong.

@Bernd , Unfortunately, no. I couldn't find a solution...
